# Angularjs ngResource multiple web service call collision

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am developing a project using angularjs. I am using ngResource for web service call. In my application there is a web service call which is running every 30 sec. Now I am facing an issue that in some situation web service called by user action and web service which is running automatically are colliding each other. I want to avoid it. How can I do it?

```
setInterval(function () {
                       $scope.getAllReports();
                     }   
                  }, 30000);



reportService.factory('Reports', function ($resource, AppSettings) {
    return $resource(AppSettings.api_url + 'reports/:reportId', {
        reportId: '@reportId'
    }, {
        getReports: {
          method: 'POST'
       }

    });
});
```

Please check the demo

http://jsfiddle.net/Kn3Tc/79/

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should consider using [$interval](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24interval) (Angular's wrapper for window.setInterval)

It ensures that any changes to the scope will be reflected elsewhere.

In your controller you could also reset your interval every time the user manually clicks on the button it to avoid collision (if I understood correctly what you want):

```
var interval;
function startInterval() {
interval = $interval(function () {
        $scope.results = myService.get();
    }, 30000);  
}

  $scope.advanceSearch = function() {
        $scope.results = myService.get();
        $interval.cancel(interval);
        startInterval();
  };
  startInterval();
```

Also dont forget to add $interval as a dependency.

Link : http://plnkr.co/edit/AuLJjiSLsscimvZC5Spi